# Flash/Flex Builder (Eclipse) - TortoiseSVN 1.7 with Subclipse 1.8 - svn options not in IDE?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, tortoisesvn, flash-builder, subclipse

I have done a checkout of a number of Flex projects from a repository folder to a local folder `C:/CodeBase/trunk`.

When I import the projects into FB (or Eclipse), there are no SVN details for any of the files. No Team options, last updated, SVN icons on the files.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7, and Subclipse 1.8. I think the problem may be that the latest TortoiseSVN stores just a single `.svn` file in the root folder, `CodeBase/trunk`, as opposed to the old system of storing an `.svn` file in every folder.

Anyone know of a fix or have you come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Team > Share Project and setup the repository details. This will make the SCM details visible to eclipse.

Comment: This would'nt help, as the project has been checked out of an SVN repository

Comment: That's the point, eclipse/FB doesn't see the repository details by default, you have to explicitly tell it by performing the share operation, that certainly works for me when I have projects I have checked out from SVN.